# I have issues updating github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I hosted my website(react app) on github pages but now when i update the content of the site and push to github..
the website is not updating or showing the updated version
i tried npm run build before git push but still not wrking

Comment: Sometimes it will take time to update the content. Spin up your site after some time

Comment: Make sure to push in master/main branch